# Sum Rows of a Data-Frame Based on Multiple Column Values

Tags: r

I am working with a large data-frame of college football players and their relevant statistics by game. It looks something like this:

```
Name      School     Year     Receptions     Receiving_Yards
Player1   College1   2004       10                200 
Player2   College2   2002       15                150
Player3   College3   2007       11                110
Player1   College1   2004       17                150
Player2   College2   2002       13                130
Player1   College1   2005       14                170
```

I want to be able to combine the rows based on multiple criteria:

1. I want to create a data frame that combines everything based on the player, school, and year in order to get his cumulative statistics for that season. Like so:

   ```
   Name      School     Year     Receptions     Receiving_Yards
   Player1   College1   2004       27                350 
   Player2   College2   2002       28                280
   Player3   College3   2007       11                110
   Player1   College1   2005       14                170
   ```
2. I want to create a data frame that combines everything just based on player and school (i.e. get me the career statistics), but gives me the year span:

   ```
   Name      School     From    to      Receptions     Receiving_Yards
   Player1   College1   2004   2005        41                520 
   Player2   College2   2002   2002        28                280
   Player3   College3   2007   2007        11                110
   ```

I'm not completely married to getting the year span for 2, as it's unlikely too many players of the same name played for the same school.

I've seen some posts on combining rows based on just one condition, but how would I do it like this when I use multiple conditions?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you `dput` (a sample of) your data?

Comment: I guess you need `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(Name, School, Year) %>% summarise_all(sum)`.  In the second case, remove the 'Year' from the `group_by`, and create `From` and `To` in summarise as `From = first(Year), to = last(Year)`

Comment: Maybe you have a typo in your question. You merge `Player2   College2` and `Player2   College1` in your both outcomes. It's not reasonable.

Comment: @DarrenTsai good catch, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use tidyverse way to solve it. I provide a base way here.

**The first outcome**

```
aggregate(. ~ Name + School + Year, df, sum)

#      Name   School Year Receptions Receiving_Yards
# 1 Player2 College2 2002         28             280
# 2 Player1 College1 2004         27             350
# 3 Player1 College1 2005         14             170
# 4 Player3 College3 2007         11             110
```

---

**The second outcome**

```
a <- aggregate(cbind(Receptions, Receiving_Yards) ~ Name + School, df, sum)
b <- aggregate(Year ~ Name + School, df, range)
merge(a, b)

#      Name   School Receptions Receiving_Yards Year.1 Year.2
# 1 Player1 College1         41             520   2004   2005
# 2 Player2 College2         28             280   2002   2002
# 3 Player3 College3         11             110   2007   2007
```

---

**Solution Using `dplyr`**

```
library(dplyr)

# (1)
df %>% group_by(Name, School, Year) %>% summarise_all(sum)

# (2)
df %>% group_by(Name, School) %>%
  summarise(From = first(Year), To = last(Year),
            Receptions = sum(Receptions),
            Receiving_Yards = sum(Receiving_Yards))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `data.table` alternative:

```
library(data.table)
df1<-copy(df)
setDT(df1)
df1[,`:=`(From=first(Year),To=last(Year)),by=.(Name,School)
][,lapply(.SD,sum),by=.(Name,School,From,To),.SDcols=c("Receptions","Receiving_Yards")]
```

Output:

```
     Name   School  From   To     Receptions Receiving_Yards
1: Player2 College2 2002 2002         28             280
2: Player1 College1 2004 2005         41             520
3: Player3 College3 2007 2007         11             110
```

The other part:

```
df1<-copy(df)
setDT(df1)
df1[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=.(Name,School,Year)]
```

or if you don't want to remake the data.table, then drop the columns from the last part(that led to the first output)

```
#df1<-copy(df) No need,see next
#setDT(df1) No need since you're using the same object as previously used
df1[,`:=`(From=NULL,To=NULL)]
df1[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=.(Name,School,Year)]
df1
```

Output:

```
      Name   School Year Receptions Receiving_Yards
1: Player1 College1 2004         27             350
2: Player2 College2 2002         28             280
3: Player3 College3 2007         11             110
4: Player1 College1 2005         14             170
```